# What is more safe in MySQL, one field or many?

Tags: mysql, database, field

I use PHP and MySQL. Lets say I have many IDs stored for later.

**Example**

After enter there is a new value. This might be an array.

```
prefix-1232
pref-5453
prefix54432
pref-2233
```

As time goes I want to add more IDs to this "array" or what it might end up being. As I see it I have two choices.

**1. Save the values as one big value in MySQL, maybe as a json converted array.**

The benefit would be that it's faster to build. The downside which also is my question is if this method is insecure becuase I save all the IDs at the same time? If there is an error all values will be lost at once.

**2. Save every value as new row in a new table (edited, not database)**

The benefit would be that if I affect one row the rest of the values are not affected. The downside is that it takes more time to build and maybe other errors might accur instead.

Which method is the safest, most correct and why?

Comment: "there is an error all values will be lost at once." This should be that is why transactions were invented, i believe you are not using transactions. In this case you may end up with duplicated data/ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal SQL solution is to add each row as a separate row in a new *table* (not a new *database*).  This has many advantages:

- The insertion is easy -- just inserting a row into a table.
- Removing a value is easy -- just delete a row from a table.
- Removing duplicates is easy -- and can even be enforced by the database.
- Finding the presence of a single value is easy -- and can use an index.

The only time (in my opinion) when you would want to store the values in a JSON array is when you get the data that way and you just want to return the entire value. The array is essentially a blob.  This opinion is less strong in databases that have native JSON support for parsing such values.

Comment: Ok, I'm convinced. When doing this, is it correct to only add one column for it with varchar(255) unique? In my case I don't see how I could need an ID column autoincreased, even if it's best practice?